# jQuery 1.6 type property is undefined

Tags: jquery, properties, jquery-1.6

I can't seem to get the type property in jQuery 1.6

```
<div id="div_id">
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$.each('#div_id input',function(index,value){
    var input_type = $(this).prop('type')
    alert(input_type);
    /*
    switch(input_type) {
         case 'checkbox':
            $(this).prop('checked',false);
            break;
                //more cases here
        default:
        this.value = '';
    }*/
});
```

see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/ccHmw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've misunderstood the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function, which accepts an array or object (as opposed to a selector).  When you pass a string to `$.each()`, jQuery iterates over all the characters in the string (in most browsers).

To fix the issue you can pass the selector to jQuery and either use the result in `$.each()`, or call `.each()` on the result:

```
$('#div_id input').each(function(index,value){
    var input_type = $(this).prop('type');
    /* ... */
});
```

See your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccHmw/9/).

If you're feeling bold, you can ditch jQuery inside the function and access the property directly, increasing efficiency and reducing code:

```
var input_type = this.type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though Andy E is right about the `$.each`, it makes more sense to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) for `type`, as `prop()` should only be used for boolean type attributes:

```
$('#div_id input').each(function() {
    var input_type = $(this).attr('type');
    alert(input_type);
    /*
    switch(input_type) {
         case 'checkbox':
            $(this).prop('checked',false);
            break;
                //more cases here
        default:
        this.value = '';
    }*/
});
```

Comment: -1, this is wrong. `type` most certainly *is* a property. As are most attribute names.

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/prop/, it seems to me that `prop` should be used for attributes that are toggled like checked and disabled.  I just don't see how `type` is a property.

Comment: Obviously your answer proves that `prop()` works, but I still hold that it makes more sense to use `attr()` for `type`.

Comment: it seems they are interchangable but i thought that prop was replacing att and according to the documentation given by @RTPMatt type is an att

Comment: `prop()` does not replace `attr()`.  I tend to think of it in terms of attributes are what live in the default markup and properties are what I can toggle with js, like checked and disabled.

Comment: @Scott: it is better to use `prop()` for a few reasons. One reason is it's marginally faster than `attr()` and the second reason is that `attr("type")` will return `undefined` if no `type` attribute is present, `prop()` will return `"text"` [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/ADGB6/).

Comment: @Andy - So you are saying that the jQuery team is wrong when they say that `type` should accessed via `attr()`?  Check out http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/.

Comment: @Scott: That says it is the *preferred* usage, but at the same time I disagree with it and don't think it should be for the reasons I stated in my previous comment. It's up to them how they tell people to use their library, but you certainly can't expect anyone to be perfect and get everything right. It is perfectly valid in HTML to omit the `type` attribute and some may do so as a means of reducing markup and data transfer. If those people follow the advice on their page they'll just end up here on SO asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: Additional- if it were me, I wouldn't be using either in this case.  I'd go for the DOM property directly on the element, e.g. `this.type`.  Fast, efficient and less markup; nothing can go wrong.

Comment: @Andy - I agree ... `this.type` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following to get attributes values

$(this).attr("type");

Answer (score 0):

type is an attribute not a property, see here:

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/